# Keyboard size too big in landscape mode in a mobile device

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website that will be used in a tablet mostly if not always in landscape mode. However, when someone taps into an input box the keyboard takes half the size of the screen in landscape mode which is a lot. It is fine is portrait mode but half the screen is way too much. Is there a way to popup smaller screen in landscape mode using CSS or is this something that has to be done from the browser setting

Comment: the keyboard dimension is different across devices, and in some case it is part of the page and it push up the page content, in some device the keyboard appears in overlay such as a fixed element do. if you whant check potrait and landscape mode you can use  orientation media queries `@media (orientation: landscape)` and `@media (orientation: potrait)`

Comment: Is it possible to change keyboard size using css after I check portrait or landscape mode

Comment: the Keyboard is part of OS so, CSS does not affect it

Comment: Can you share the URL to try it or share the code?

Comment: Since you cannot modify the keyboard size, the best you can do in this situation is to set your input element automatically into view. `document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView()`

Answer (score 7):

@jedu you are more user concerned if the user is mostly using the tab or mobile in landscape mode he would have already adjusted it's keyboard size accordingly to be more productive in his task.

The more or less we can do is to make the page appear more accessible in the landscape mode using landscape orientation css by writing media queries.

We can't size the keyboard of the user. But we can prompt a user about changing its keyboard size for more accessibility of the website as a message